# How to remove nodes from patroni postgresql cluster?

Tags: patroni

we have 4 node patroni postgresql cluster on production. We try to remove 2 node from cluster.
How can i do this?
Regards.

Answer (score 3):

just stop the patroni!
https://github.com/zalando/patroni/issues/1377

But we want to delete only one node from patroni cluster.

sudo systemctl stop patroni.service